# Symfony2 + Codeception gives "You must override the KernelTestCase::createKernel()"

Tags: symfony, codeception

I created a new test that inherits from WebTestCase. When I run my codeception tests, I get the following error:

```
 [RuntimeException] You must override the KernelTestCase::createKernel() method.
```

It is very unclear to me with what I need to override it. What I want is a client that can call a certain URI to get my http response

This is the test:

```
  public function testSearchAction()
    {
        $searchUri = '/search';
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('GET', $searchUri);
        $response = $client->getResponse();
        $this->assertSame(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
```

This is my unit.suite.yml file

class_name: UnitTester

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony2:
            app_path: '../../app'
            var_path: '../../app'
        - Doctrine2:
            depends: Symfony2
        - AppBundle\Helper\Unit
```

Comment: Why are you trying to run WebTestCase test with Codeception?

Comment: Use Symfony2 module of Codeception or run your WebTestCase tests with phpunit.

Comment: Ok I extended the codeception test case, ```class SearchControllerTest extends  \Codeception\TestCase\Test``` how do I get the client then ?

Comment: I extended WebTestCase, because it has the Symfony client with which I can maken calls by using request and response

Comment: Read http://codeception.com/docs/04-FunctionalTests  Cept format is more suitable for this kind of testing than Test.

Comment: I use Behat for that, but I still want to do some unit tests on my controller actions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100965/discussion-between-naktibalda-and-nealv).

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into the same problem when trying to integrate existing tests extending from WebTestCase into Codeception. Setting `KERNEL_DIR` in `tests/functional/_bootstrap.php` solved the issue for me:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['KERNEL_DIR'] = __DIR__ . '/../../app/';
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run basics WebTestCase (or simple PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase).
In your unit.suite.ym file, add the boostrap settings :

```
# tests/unit.suite.ym
modules:
    enabled:
        - Symfony2:
            app_path: '../../app'
            var_path: '../../app'
        - Doctrine2:
            depends: Symfony2
        - AppBundle\Helper\Unit
bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
```

Create the tests/unit/_bootstrap.php  file

```
<?php
$_SERVER['KERNEL_DIR'] = __DIR__ . '/../../app/';
```

The loading of _bootstrap file is done by the listener Codeception\Subscriber\Bootstrap::loadBootstrap()

Answer (score 0):

Exception *You must override the KernelTestCase::createKernel() method* can be solved by setting *KERNEL_DIR* parameter in file app/phpunit.xml.dist.
By default, section concerning *KERNEL_DIR* in this file is commented.

The full path to the kernel may look like:

```
<php>
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="C:/symfonyProjects/project1/app" />
</php>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error with Symfony 4, the solution has changed.

In Symfony 2 and 3, you could set the KERNEL_DIR in tests/functional/_bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['KERNEL_DIR'] = __DIR__ . '/../../app/';
```

In Symfony 4, you should set the KERNEL_CLASS in tests/functional/_bootstrap.php:

```
<?php
$_SERVER['KERNEL_CLASS'] = App\Kernel::class;
```