# how to run codeception tests and Symfony tests

Tags: php, symfony, testing, codeception

I m using symfony3 with codeception

I have a hierarchy like this in my project

```
tests/
    UserBundle/
              mySuperTest.php
    unit/
              myUnitTest.php
    functional/
              myFunctionalTest.php
```

When i run

```
php bin/codecept run
```

it only show me the running of myUnitTest and myFunctionalTest, but not mySuperTest which is an extend of symfony/webTestCase.

How to run all my total suites including UserBundle ?

regards.

Comment: have you got a UserBundle.suite.yml file in tests/ directory?

Comment: nop I will try to create it

Comment: thank you very much it gives me new error i can pursue on my work

Comment: You should include the new error message and continue this question, or delete it altogether.

Comment: the new error message is `[RuntimeException] You must override the KernelTestCase::createKernel() method.  `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37391914/366348

Comment: OR
   `/**
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected static function getKernelClass()
    {
        return 'AppKernel';
    }` in your class is more convenient for me compared to your post suggestion